# How to get msn contact list with Python?

Tags: python, msn

How can I get msn contact list with a Python script having username and password?

Answer (score 1):

There are [lots](http://blitiri.com.ar/p/msnlib/) and [lots](http://code.google.com/p/pymsn/) and [lots](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWords) of MSN client modules for Python.

Comment: *msnlib* seems to only work with MSNP version 8, which is ancient, and *Pymsn's* actual web site is at http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/Pymsn — the Google Code site has nothing on it.

Comment: Seems Twisted also use MSNP version 8 http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.words.protocols.msn.html